# What is the meaning of a distribution measure?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-distributions

On the set $\mathbb{R}$ of all real numbers, I then randomly pick up a number $x$. Assume that $\mathbb{R}$ is unevenly distributed, namely, for example, let's say, it is more likely to get a big, positive number than a negative one; or it's more likely to pick up an irrational number than a rational one.

To fomulate this, one way is to consider a $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ (for example, let's consider the Borel $\sigma$-algebra) and a probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ on it. That is, we consider a probability space $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),\mathbb{P})$. This formulation is very clear to me.

Now, let's consider another way to formulate our situation. To say that  $x$ is randomly chosen, I consider it as a random variable. That is: let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ be another probability space and let $X:(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ be a random variable. So, now I imagine that when I randomly pick a $x$ then I can think of it as $X(\omega)$, for some $\omega\in\Omega$. And, how to measure the likelihood of an event! I consider the distribution measure $P_{X}$, defined by
$$P_{X}(A)=\mu(\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)\in A\}),\quad \text{for any }A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}).$$

**My question**: Are the two formulations identical?

*A similar situation is as follows:*

I randomly pick up a real number $x$ (as in the above experiment) and my friend randomly picks up a number in an infinite sequence containing only 0 and 1 (some thing like: 0,1,1,0,0,1,0,...). Since the distributions are uneven, one way to formulate the problem is to consider the probabilty space $(\mathbb{R}\times Y,\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\otimes \mathcal{Y},\mathbb{P})$. Here $Y=\{0,1\}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra $\{\{0\},\{1\},\{0,1\},\emptyset\}$. And $\mathbb{P}$ is some probability measure to quantify how likely $(x,y)$ happens when I randomly pick up $x$ and my friend randomly chooses $y$.

But, *is the following formulation the same?* Again, I consider two random variables: $X:(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)\rightarrow (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ and $\mathbb{Y}: (\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)\rightarrow (Y,\mathcal{Y})$. Here the domains of these random variables are the same. To measure the likelihood of an event, I consider the distribution measure $P_{(X,\mathbb{Y})}$ defined by:

$$P_{(X,\mathbb{Y})}(A,B)=\mathbb{P}(\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)\in A, \mathbb{Y}(\omega)\in B\}),\quad \text{for any }A\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}), B\in\mathcal{Y}.$$

Comment: identical in what sense? Maybe this could help you to answer yourself: every probability measure $P$ in $\mathbb{R}$ can be defined from a random variable, just pick $X$ the identity function and $\Omega =\mathbb{R}$, by the other side every random variable induces a probability measure in $\mathbb{R}$, this is what you are asking?

Comment: @Masacroso "identical" in the way we think or formulate our problem. I agree that if we just pick $\Omega$ the same as $\mathbb{R}$ then my question seems absurd. But let's look at the second part of the question when you have 2 random variables. I am not clear whether there is some meaning on the distribution measure induced by a random variable.

Comment: @Oliver Thks for your response. My question is about the formulations or the meaning of distribution measures, not the definitions.

Comment: in your second example: if $\mathbb{P}$ and $P_{X,\Bbb Y}$ are identical yes, your results will be identical, however $P_{X,\Bbb Y}$ can be induced from infinitely many distinct random variables $X$ and $\Bbb Y$.

Comment: @Hana: The pullback measure $P_X$ is the meaning of the distribution of a random variable $X$

Comment: @Oliver By "meaning" I meant the philosophy, the behind idea. Do you think that all the formulations mentioned above are correct? By "correct" I meant when I encounter a specific problem, any formulation mentioned above would lead to the same conclusion.

Comment: @hana: The idea is fully contained in the definition: you have observables (called random variables) and you want to gauge how likely they attain certain values (in some set $A$).  $P[X\in  A]$. the observables could have numeric values, vector values, etc.

Comment: @ Masacroso Of course if $\mathbb{P}$ and $P_{X,\mathbb{Y}}$ are identical then the two are identical. But it's not my concern here. The question is about the formulation. That is, let's assume that the part here is just the beginning of some bigger problem. So the first step is to consider a formulation for the randomness of $x$. Then the second step is to use it for the prolem. My concern is: whether both formulations lead to the same result.

Answer (score 1):

A measurable function (also know as random variable, or observable) $X$ from a probability measure space $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mathbb{P})$ into some measurable space space $(S,\mathscr{S})$, induces a probability measure $P_X$ on $(S,\mathscr{S})$ given as
$$ P_X(A)=\mathbb{P}[\{X\in A\}],\quad A\in\mathscr{S}
$$
This probability measure $P_X$ is called the distribution of $X$. This gives the mathematical framework to measure the "likelihood" that our observables fall within some range $A$ of values.

Given two random variables $X:(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mathbb{P})\rightarrow (S,\mathscr{S})$ and $Y:(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mathbb{P})\rightarrow (T,\mathscr{T})$, the function $U=(X,Y):(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mathbb{P})\rightarrow(S\times T,\mathscr{S}\otimes\mathscr{T})$ is also a random variable (Here $\mathscr{S}\otimes\mathscr{T}$ is the $\sigma$--algebra generated but the sets of the form $A\times B$ where $A\in\mathscr{S}$ and $B\in\mathscr{T}$. The joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$, $P_{X,Y}$ is the distribution of $U$. So is $A\times B\in\mathscr{S}\otimes\mathscr{T}$,
$$
P_U(A\times B):=P_{X,Y}(A\times B)=\mathbb{P}[\{X\in A\}\cap \{Y\in B\}]
$$